# Trigger multiple animations on the same element onclick from current position

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to move the red shape from one icon to another when clicking on the icons. For testing purposes I have created 4 individual buttons.

The problem with the current code:

1. The buttons are working only once.
2. The red shape won't start the animation from the current position.

I have also tried with animation-play-state paused but I didn't manage to make it work.

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation1);
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation2);
document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation3);
document.getElementById("btn4").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation4);


function controlAnimation1() {
  const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
  menu.classList.add('anim1');
}

function controlAnimation2() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.classList.add('anim2');
  }

  function controlAnimation3() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.classList.add('anim3');
  }

  function controlAnimation4() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.classList.add('anim4');
  }
```

```css
#leftnav {
background-color: #fc638f;
width: 6rem;
height: 35rem;
border-radius: 25px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 1.5rem;
margin-left: 1.5rem;
position: relative;
}

#container2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.iconsclass {
    margin: 25px;
}

#container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

#buttonsoverlay {
    background-color: red;
    height: 70px;
    width: 5rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 35px;
    margin-top: 1.86rem;
    position: absolute;
}

#alloverlays {
    padding-top: 22.25rem;
}

.anim1 {
    animation: anim1 0.5s forwards;
}

.anim2 {
    animation: anim2 0.5s forwards;
}

.anim3 {
    animation: anim3 0.5s forwards;
}

.anim4 {
    animation: anim4 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
    from {}
    to {padding-top: 4.7rem;}
}

@keyframes anim2 {
    from {}
    to {padding-top: 10.5rem;}
}

@keyframes anim3 {
    from {}
    to {padding-top: 16.4rem;}
}

@keyframes anim4 {
    from {}
    to {padding-top: 22.25rem;}
}

#topbuttonsoverlay {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    margin-left: 3.15rem;
    --mask: radial-gradient(30px at 0 0,#0000 98%,#000);
    -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
    mask: var(--mask);

}

#bottombuttonsoverlay {
    background-color: black;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    margin-top: 4.1rem;
    margin-left: 3.15rem;
    --mask: radial-gradient(30px at 0 100%,#0000 98%,#000);
    -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
    mask: var(--mask);
}
```

```html
    <main>
        <div id="leftnav">

            <div id="icons">
                <div id="container2">
                    <img class="iconsclass" src="/images/apple.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
                    <img class="iconsclass" id="firstbtn" src="/images/home.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
                    <img class="iconsclass" id="secondbtn" src="/images/play.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
                    <img class="iconsclass" id="thirdbtn" src="/images/play2.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
                    <img class="iconsclass" id="forthbtn" src="/images/send1.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="alloverlays">
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="buttonsoverlay"></div>
                    <div id="topbuttonsoverlay"></div>
                    <div id="bottombuttonsoverlay"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <button id="btn1">btn1</button>
        <button id="btn2">btn2</button>
        <button id="btn3">btn3</button>
        <button id="btn4">btn4</button>

    </main>
```

Comment: [Remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) previously added class name and then add the new one, in every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using CSS animation keyframes is that once they have run the system will assume they have run and not run them again if the class is never removed.

There is the further complication that you want the object to move to a position, stay there and then do the next move from that position.

A way of achieving this is to scrap using CSS animation keyframes and instead use transition on padding-top. In the JS you write the new value in the style attribute - this ensures the value is 'remembered' (if you set it through adding a class it gets removed when you remove that class).

```html
<style>
  #leftnav {
    background-color: #fc638f;
    width: 6rem;
    height: 35rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #container2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .iconsclass {
    margin: 25px;
  }
  
  #container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
  
  #buttonsoverlay {
    background-color: red;
    height: 70px;
    width: 5rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 35px;
    margin-top: 1.86rem;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  #alloverlays {
    padding-top: 22.25rem;
    transition: padding-top 0.5s;
  }
  
  #topbuttonsoverlay {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    margin-left: 3.15rem;
    --mask: radial-gradient(30px at 0 0, #0000 98%, #000);
    -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
    mask: var(--mask);
  }
  
  #bottombuttonsoverlay {
    background-color: black;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    margin-top: 4.1rem;
    margin-left: 3.15rem;
    --mask: radial-gradient(30px at 0 100%, #0000 98%, #000);
    -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
    mask: var(--mask);
  }
</style>
<main>
  <div id="leftnav">

    <div id="icons">
      <div id="container2">
        <img class="iconsclass" src="/images/apple.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
        <img class="iconsclass" id="firstbtn" src="/images/home.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
        <img class="iconsclass" id="secondbtn" src="/images/play.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
        <img class="iconsclass" id="thirdbtn" src="/images/play2.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
        <img class="iconsclass" id="forthbtn" src="/images/send1.png" alt="" style="width: 40px;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="alloverlays">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="buttonsoverlay"></div>
        <div id="topbuttonsoverlay"></div>
        <div id="bottombuttonsoverlay"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button id="btn1">btn1</button>
  <button id="btn2">btn2</button>
  <button id="btn3">btn3</button>
  <button id="btn4">btn4</button>

</main>
<script>
  document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation1);
  document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation2);
  document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation3);
  document.getElementById("btn4").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation4);


  function controlAnimation1() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.style.paddingTop = "4.7rem";
  }

  function controlAnimation2() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.style.paddingTop = "10.5rem";
  }

  function controlAnimation3() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.style.paddingTop = "16.4rem";
  }

  function controlAnimation4() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('#alloverlays');
    menu.style.paddingTop = "22.25rem";
  }
</script>
```